# MX lookup query to resolve ALL subdomains

Tags: php, dns, mx-record

I am searching on problem that i am facing that suppose, i am having a domain name "abhinav.com" and my mail address is "mail@abhinav.com".

But i want that if someone types a email like "john@gmail.com.abhinav.com" and sends the mail, then the email is received by my mail server.

I am searching for the MX records settings which would be helpful for me to proceed in my research.

As is have the only lead that this is only done by DNS settings. if someone faced the same problem earlier please do help.

if something is not clear please refer to the website because these guys had done the exact same thing.

URL:- http://getnotify.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question, you will need to create an `MX` record with a `*` (wildcard) as the name and add the mail server so it will accepted ALL subdomains.

You can see this working on my domain:

http://mxtoolbox.com/SuperTool.aspx?action=mx%3agoogle.com.kitson-online.co.uk&run=toolpage#

As a side note, I think you may be getting confused with how this system works. It's not tracking by adding a domain suffix but rather by adding an image with an external source to the email which then downloads the content from the server and stores the IP/Time of Download into in a database.

**Example:**

1. john@gmail.com.getnotify.com -> goes to mail server from MX record of domain getnotify.com
2. getnotify.com strips `.getnotify.com` from email string, adds an image with a link to external source (`img` name is probably associated to your account) and then relays the email to john@gmail.com.
3. When the email is received and viewed, the email renders within the mail client and attempts to pull external `img` source from getnotify.com.
4. getnotify.com can see this `img` request has checked in and then adds this data along with IP address (that's your Geographic Data) to a database.

I can tell you now that this will not work 100% of the time as most clients will not render emails until the users accepts to download from external sources. Plus, this is traceable as the content will be available to recipient within the source and headers just not available at first glance.

*See extract taken from [GetNotify FAQ](http://www.getnotify.com/faq/#How_does_GetNotify_Email_tracking_work)*

> **How does GetNotify Email tracking work?**
>
> GetNotify works by adding a small invisible tracking image in your outgoing Emails. When your Email recipient opens your Email, this image gets downloaded from GetNotify server. So GetNotify will know exactly when your sent Email was opened and it notifies you through an Email that your sent Email is read by the recipient.

Comment: Hi Kitson, Thank you for the response.

Well I am aware about sending an image in the email and getting all the details but what I am not able to do is get all the emails on my email.

I tried using * - wildcard entry in sub-domain and mx but it still does not work. If I am able to receive all the email then I can certainly code things from there.

Thank you in advance.

Test Domain: joomlaupgradeservice.com

Answer (score 0):

Using third party email service just for tracking to business email is not an best practice. Using this kind of service allows the tracking provider to use your contacts for their business. They know what you have sent and can track all the information before you do and even then when you are not in loop so it's better not to entertain any non secured third party services like this.

If you are using outlook for your business email then their is an inbuilt feature, take a look at this 
https://www.spark.co.nz/help/internet-email/webservices/how-to-request-a-read-receipt-in-outlook-or-webmail/

If you are using Gsuite then here is an solution for that
https://support.google.com/a/answer/1383374?hl=en

Hope the solution helps!